# Datasheet for XC370696P (Smoke Detector IC)

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, datasheet, smoke-sensor

I decided on a whim to take apart an old smoke detector that desperately needed replacing, and after some ripping, I got to the guts of the thing.

[image: smoke detector guts]

Neat stuff.

Clearly the brains of the detector is that DIP IC on the right of the board: Motorola XC370696P. Here's a closeup of the part.

[image: Motorola XC370696P]

The internet is surprisingly quiet about this IC.  Any insight on what this part is, or where the datasheet lives?

Comment: With Motorola, the "XC" prefix means "Engineering sample." MC would have meant a fully qualified part. Don't know if that helps any, though.

Comment: looks pretty old 1998 , if it had a radioactive sensor, its probably clogged with dust.

Comment: @Tony: 1998 is spot on.

Comment: @jonk: I never knew about the XC/MC distinction.  I guess the "engineering samples" were good enough for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [RE46C120](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RE46C120), a similar device made by Microchip.

Its datasheet claims compatiblity with MC145017 and MC14467. I think it may very well be pin-compatible to your device too (pin15=detect).

Comment: Peter, this is a fantastic find!  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was designed by Freescale which had Motorola roots and manufacturing agreements with Mot but is now owned by NXP.

I also believe this is a proprietary part exclusive to those who paid for a license to build with these parts which is covered by an NDA.

Comment: That's what I feared.

Comment: feel free to reverse engineer the transfer functions on each pin

Comment: Nice way to pass a sunday afternoon.